# JavaMail Gmail issue. "Ready to start TLS" then fails

Tags: java, ssl, smtp, gmail

```
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("blah@gmail.com"));
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("blah@gmail.com"));
    generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings");
    String emailBody = "Test email";
    generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
    System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "user", "password");
    transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

I also installed the gmail smtp certificate in my keystore 
    openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning    javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP i80sm10888185wmf.11 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO uk-lon01-mws07
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2.220.210.180]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS (BOMBS OUT AT THIS POINT)
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket     to TLS;
  nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during     handshake
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2046)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:711)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at com.lawrenceadams.Mail.generateAndSendEmail(Mail.java:50)
at com.lawrenceadams.Mail.main(Mail.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection     during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
at     sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:598)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:525)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2041)
... 9 more
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
... 15 more
```

Can anyone help? Been struggling on this for the last couple hours.

Comment: What TLS protocol are you using? Additionally, why are you using port 465 instead of 587 for your keystore?

Comment: I'm using port 587. check mail server properties in code

Comment: I was referring to your comment RE the gmail smtp certificate you had installed.

Comment: sorry corrections. an online reference pointed me to get the certificate from that location.

Comment: I assumed the certificate would cover all ports under that host

Comment: The main issue is `Remote host closed connection during  handshake`.  With the current information it is impossible to say how this is caused but it might be related to using an old Java version, deep packet inspection firewalls in the network etc. Enabling SSL debugging might help to narrow down the problem.