# Enabling ssl debug for java in intellij

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea, jvm

Following on from my problem here

[previous issue trying to send java mail via tls/ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259578/javamail-gmail-issue-ready-to-start-tls-then-fails?noredirect=1#comment65860189_39259578)

i am now trying to add ssl debugging in Intellij.

In the oracle article it gives an example

```
    java  -Djavax.net.debug=all  \
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStore
    SSLSocketClientWithClientAuth bongos 2001 /index.html
```

How do i configure my environment for a standalone application which runs via main() method?

Comment: You mean menu->run-configuration->Application->VM options ?

Comment: yes running a main method called inside class com.mypackage.Entrypoint.java what is the actual command that i entered in the vm options box?

Answer (score 17):

All you need to do is edit your Run Configuration.

> Run -> Edit Configurations

And then under the VM options enter the options you want to use. For example

> -Djavax.net.debug=all

should be all you need for ssl debugging.

Comment: it should be but it isn't, at least not in my case.